# Como evito que el evento matDrawer.toggle() renderice toda la pagina?

Tags: angular

Estoy usando matDrawer para desplegar un menu lateral , sin embargo al dar clic en el boton donde tengo el evento hace que los elementos que tengo en un mat-drawer-content se renderice de nuevo llamando nuevamente las funciones. Como puedo evitar dicho comportamiento?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si no mostras el codigo que produce eso, va a ser dificil que te ayuden

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.